# Byte by byte need to xor but its showing as integer and getting lost of precision error?

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I have socket application and I can read byte by byte and I can push all the byte into one single array. I read like below.So I will have 12+bodylen bytes.

```
int messageID = r.readUnsignedShort();
int bodyLen = r.readUnsignedShort();       
byte[] phoneNum = new byte[6];
r.readFully(phoneNum);  
int serialNum = r.readUnsignedShort();     
byte[] messageBody = new byte[bodyLen];    
r.readFully(messageBody);
byte checkCode = r.readByte();
```

Next I do this where I create a bytebuffer and later I tried to run the for loop to print first to check where its byte format or not I receive it in integer values cause one of the value is -110? and also I receive error on this line xor = (byte)xor ^ (byte)fullMessage[sf]; possible loss of precision?

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12+bodyLen);
          buf.putShort((short)messageID);
          buf.put((byte)bodyLen);
          buf.put(phoneNum);
          buf.putShort((short)serialNum);
          buf.put(messageBody);

          byte[] fullMessage=buf.array();

          int xor = 0;
          for(int sf=0,s=fullMessage.length;sf<s;sf++){
              xor ^= fullMessage[sf];
              fullMessage[sf] = (byte)xor;
             // System.out.println("\n\nprint value for : "+sf+"  "+"value is:"+xor);
                 // do your XOR operations -> xor operator is ^
          }
          System.out.println("\n\nfinal xor is :"+xor+"  "+Integer.toHexString(xor));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First since you are doing:

```
int serialNum = r.readUnsignedShort();
```

Replace

```
buf.put((byte)serialNum);
```

by

```
buf.putShort((short)serialNum);
```

The sign skews the value, but that can be repaired by: `& 0xFFFF`.

Bytes are xorred as:

```
byte x = (byte) 0xA0; // Negative signed byte value
byte y = ...
byte z = (byte)(x ^ y); // Xor is done on int
```

So the xorring will be:

```
    int xor = 0;
    for (int sf = 0, s = fullMessage.length; sf < s; sf++) {
        xor ^= fullMessage[sf];
        fullMessage[sf] = (byte)xor;
    }
```

Using that 0 is the neutral element of `^`.

Comment: The same principle. Of course, when it was not intentional to shorten the message bytes, by leaving some out.

Comment: I have updated my question but I get wrong values for xor it suppose to be just one bye ?

Comment: I left this as buf.put(phoneNum);? is that fine ?

Comment: I am keep getting different xor value for the same input data ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The xorring propagates from small index upwards. I do not know the requirements so the puzzling fun is for you. `put(byte[])` seems fine. On **the byte buffer** do `buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);` Maybe a reversed order of the shorts is expected. But that you would have seen if the length was far off on reading too.

Answer (score 1):

`xor = (byte) ((byte)xor ^ (byte)fullMessage[sf]);`